# Fonts not loading in IE11

Tags: html, css, fonts, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to figure out why the fonts aren't loading in the body section of my articles. This only happens in Internet Explorer.

Example article: https://outline.com/zzsgGV

I'm fetching from this: https://outline.com/css/outline.css with the following calls to the fonts. I've added the .eot calls and the files are all available.

Some possible theories

":root" is not supported in IE11

font variables are not supported in IE11

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro Bold';
    src:url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-Bold.eot);
    src:url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-Bold.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-Bold.woff) format('woff'),url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-Bold.ttf) format('truetype'),url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-Bold.svg#3ba63f82a1b13c399d199d455e95ce26) format('svg');
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:700
}
@font-face{
    font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro Bold';
    src:url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-BoldItalic.eot);
    src:url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-BoldItalic.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-BoldItalic.woff) format('woff'),url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-BoldItalic.ttf) format('truetype'),url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-BoldItalic.svg#fc87d529a9b2a903681f36cd7c9d9a39) format('svg');
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:700
}
@font-face{
    font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro';
    src:url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-Italic.eot);
    src:url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-Italic.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-Italic.woff) format('woff'),url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-Italic.ttf) format('truetype'),url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-Italic.svg#e62a4d531f55b2f8bdfd398331ec8604) format('svg');
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:400
}
@font-face{
    font-family:'Adobe Garamond Pro';
    src:url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-Regular.eot);
    src:url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-Regular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-Regular.woff) format('woff'),url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-Regular.ttf) format('truetype'),url(../fonts/AGaramondPro-Regular.svg#1eabc8b27c1d378ed9b1f5dd58b5095c) format('svg');
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400
}
:root{
    --base-font-weight:400;
    --base-font-size:22px/1.62;
    --sys-font-family:"Adobe Garamond Pro","Georgia","Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    --zh-font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue","PingFang SC","Hiragino Sans GB","Droid Sans Fallback","Microsoft YaHei",sans-serif;
    --sub-font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue","PingFang SC","Hiragino Sans GB","Droid Sans Fallback","Microsoft YaHei",sans-serif;
    --base-font-family:var(--sys-font-family),var(--zh-font-family);
    --code-font-family:Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Courier New";
    --base-color:#444443;
    --emphasis-color:#222223;
    --link-color:#0985ce;
    --link-hover-color:#0985ce;
    --figure-color:#666665;
    --blockquote-color:#666664;
    --code-color:#808080;
    --pre-code-color:#4c4c4c
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS variables are not supported in **Internet explorer 11.**

[Browser support (caniuse.com)](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20var)

[image]